# Calculating width to create continuous horizontal bar in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I have a horizontal timeline where I plot events over time in D3.js:

[image: see here]

Now, I would like to "fill" the gaps between the events, so calculating the width of each bar (similar as a Gantt chart).
This is what I would like to achieve:

[image: see here]

My logic was to have the position of the i+1 minus position, like this:

```
.attr('width', function(d,i){ 
        barWidth = xScale(barData2[i+1].eventTime) - xScale(barData2[i].eventTime);
        return barWidth;
     })
```

(where barWidth is an empty variable and barData2 is the data)

This does the job, but also breaks the code as it will not continue the rest of the code:

[image: see here]

I've tried calculating this in various ways, but no luck. Any suggestions?

```js
var barData2 = [{
  eventTime: new Date("Mon May 11 2020 18:25:43 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)")
}, {
  eventTime: new Date("Mon May 11 2020 18:34:14 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)")
}, {
  eventTime: new Date("Mon May 11 2020 22:10:42 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)")
}, {
  eventTime: new Date("Mon May 11 2020 22:14:46 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)")
}, {
  eventTime: new Date("Mon May 11 2020 22:22:25 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)")
}, {
  eventTime: new Date("Mon May 11 2020 22:30:35 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)")
}, {
  eventTime: new Date("Tue May 12 2020 00:40:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)")
}, {
  eventTime: new Date("Tue May 12 2020 05:00:57 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)")
}];



var barWidth = 0;


var height = 200,
  width = 900,
  barHeight = 10;


var xScale = d3.time.scale()
  .domain([barData2[0].eventTime, barData2[(barData2.length - 1)].eventTime])
  .range([0, width - 85]);


var xScale2 = d3.time.scale()
  .domain([barData2[0].eventTime, barData2[(barData2.length - 1)].eventTime])
  .range([0, width - 85]);


var xAxisTicks = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
  .ticks(d3.timeHour.every(1));


var toolTip = d3.select('body')
  .append('div')
  .style('position', 'absolute')
  .style('padding', '0 10px')
  .style('background', 'white')
  .style('opacity', 0);

d3.select('#viz').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .style('background', '#aaa')

  .append('g')
  .selectAll('rect').data(barData2)
  .enter().append('rect')
  .attr('y', function(d, i) {
    return i * barHeight;
  })

  .attr('height', barHeight)
  .attr('width', function(d, i) {
    barWidth = xScale(barData2[i + 1].eventTime) - xScale(barData2[i].eventTime);
    return console.log("barWidth for", i, "=", barWidth), barWidth;
  })

  .attr('x', function(d, i) {
    return xScale2(barData2[i].eventTime);
  })


xGuide = d3.select('#viz svg').append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (height - 25) + ')')
  .call(xAxisTicks);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-time.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-time-format.v3.min.js"></script>

<div id="viz"></div>
```

Comment: I don't follow, please share a [mre] of your code.

Comment: I've added an example in my post above. Hope this is clear.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Do you want the idle times visualised? Please tell how these bars relate to the coloured bars from the first image

Comment: Yes, I would like the bars to be stretched untill the next event begins.

Comment: I've also added an image to show what I'd like to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get this is by just transforming your data a little bit beforehand. Note that if we have `n` events, we want to draw `n - 1` bars.

```js
var barData2 = [{
  eventTime: new Date("Mon May 11 2020 18:25:43 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)")
}, {
  eventTime: new Date("Mon May 11 2020 18:34:14 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)")
}, {
  eventTime: new Date("Mon May 11 2020 22:10:42 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)")
}, {
  eventTime: new Date("Mon May 11 2020 22:14:46 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)")
}, {
  eventTime: new Date("Mon May 11 2020 22:22:25 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)")
}, {
  eventTime: new Date("Mon May 11 2020 22:30:35 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)")
}, {
  eventTime: new Date("Tue May 12 2020 00:40:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)")
}, {
  eventTime: new Date("Tue May 12 2020 05:00:57 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)")
}];

// .slice(1) removes the first entry, because we have n events,
// we want to draw n-1 bars
barData2Processed = barData2.slice(1).map(function(d, i) {
  return {
    // Note that because we removed the first entry, this is
    // actually the previous element, not the current one
    start: barData2[i].eventTime,
    end: d.eventTime
  }
});

var barWidth = 0;
var height = 200,
  width = 900,
  barHeight = 10;

var xScale = d3.time.scale()
  .domain([barData2[0].eventTime, barData2[(barData2.length - 1)].eventTime])
  .range([0, width - 85]);

var xAxisTicks = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
  .ticks(d3.timeHour.every(1));

var toolTip = d3.select('body')
  .append('div')
  .style('position', 'absolute')
  .style('padding', '0 10px')
  .style('background', 'white')
  .style('opacity', 0);

d3.select('#viz').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .style('background', '#aaa')

  .append('g')
  .selectAll('rect').data(barData2Processed)
  .enter().append('rect')
  .attr('y', function(d, i) {
    return i * barHeight;
  })
  .attr('height', barHeight)
  .attr('width', function(d, i) {
    return xScale(d.end) - xScale(d.start);
  })
  .attr('x', function(d, i) {
    return xScale(d.start);
  })


xGuide = d3.select('#viz svg').append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (height - 25) + ')')
  .call(xAxisTicks);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-time.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-time-format.v3.min.js"></script>

<div id="viz"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will dive into this to try to understand (still new to d3 and JS). 
My next challenge is to have each eventTime on a different line, any hints to help me thinking in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean? Like a y-axis?

Comment: yes, so instead of having them stacked as a ladder, I would like to have all of the events of the same day to be on one single horizontal line. The next date on the following line and so on.

Comment: And what if one starts before midnight and ends after midnight? It'll need to be on two rows.

Comment: My tips: - Use a datetime library like luxon or moment.js to deal with timezones, they're horrible; - When processing the data, split an entry if it overflows into the next day, e.g. giving one from 09:05-12:00 and one from 12:00-12:35. Copy all other properties, including colour; - Don't use `scaleTime`, but transform the date to "number of days since `x`" where `x` can be anything (like 01-01-2000). Then, use `scaleLinear` and format the ticks using a custom `.tickFormat` function

Comment: Thanks Ruben, great tips and things to think about, very helpful!